# Rserve setting for connect to Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api, rserve

This is the first time I have tried to connect R and Tableau.

I have downloaded and installed `Rserve` successfully but every time I try to start `Rserve` is get this warning:

```
Starting Rserve...
"C:\Users\SIMON~1.HAR\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.1\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.exe" 
Warning message:
running command '"C:\Users\SIMON~1.HAR\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.1\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.exe" ' had status 127
```

I have been searching for days and couldn't find any fix.

Answer (score 0):

The Rserve() function is trying to start an application (Rserve.exe) and failed. There's a couple of things you can do.

1. Go to the "C:\Users\SIMON~1.HAR\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.1\Rserve\libs\x64\" file directory and try loading the exe yourself, troubleshoot from there.
2. use the run.Rserve() function instead of Rserve(). This will use your current R session to start the Rserve server. This means the exe doesn't need to be run. This worked well for me because I am working in an environment where I don't enough privileges to run the exe. It does mean that your R session can't do anything else while the server is running, but you can always load up 2 sessions at the same time.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up